# NSUserDefaults objectForKey() Receiving Error

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, xcode6

I was building a game in Swift that stored the user's highscore in NSUserDefaults, however later on the game kept crashing. I narrowed it down to reading the highscore of NSUserDefaults and so I made a simple app to test saving and reading values with NSUserDefaults. I run each function in order with button taps. Here's the code:

```
@IBOutlet var valueTextfield: UITextField
@IBOutlet var keyTextfield: UITextField
@IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel

@IBAction func saveData(sender: UIButton){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(valueTextfield.text, forKey: keyTextfield.text)
}
@IBAction func forceSynchronise(sender: UIButton){
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

@IBAction func refreshLabel(sender: UIButton){
    valueLabel.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(keyTextfield.text) as String
}
```

When the last function runs it throws the exception: 'fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None'. I thought that since the last line would definitely return a value, optionals weren't needed, but evidently I'm wrong.
Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this:

```
if let valueText = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(keyTextfield.text) as? String{

    valueLabel.text = valueText
}else{
    //handle nil value
}
```

This won't crash and lets you handle getting a nil value.

Comment: Ok, that's great because it stopped crashing. However, it **always** returns nil.

Comment: If it always returns nil it probably has nothing to do with the optional unwrapping. Maybe try to replace `keyTextfield.text` for the key with something you know has a value. Their might simply be no value for `keyTextfield.text`.

Comment: No, I inserted a some `println()`s and they print the correct key and also that `valueText` is `nil`

Comment: I modified some of the values to work without the textfields and now it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No prob, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

use

```
as? String
```

instead of

```
as String
```

otherwise you will get a crash on nil values.

Comment: Ok, it's stopped crashing and it's now returning nil.

Comment: `as? String` tells the compiler to convert the left to a String if possible and nil if not.  `as String?` tells the compiler the object is an optional string.  Since the conversion isn't optional and it can't be performed, it throws an exception.

Comment: @David Fair enough, but that still doesn't explain why the conversion itself is failing.